# Make can not find <sys/select.h>

Tags: c, contiki

I'm trying to compile a Contiki OS example on Ubuntu 16.10, but I'm facing the following issue:

```
$ make
```

returns

```
../../platform/slwstk6201a/./contiki-conf.h:40:26: fatal error:
sys/select.h: No such file or directory
    #include <sys/select.h>
```

When I include `<stdio.h>`, which is in the same folder (but 1 level below sys), the `<stdio.h>` include does not throw an error. This makes me believe it's an issue with permissions/path variable?

I also tried changing the include to `#include </usr/include/sys/select.h>`, but that will throw an error, complaining about another include `features.h`

Any suggestions?

Comment: Your error is saying it cannot find "linux/select.h" not "sys/select.h" - they're different files.

Comment: Whoops, I also tried looking for linux/select.h and copied the wrong error message

Comment: I'm going to guess you need the kernel headers package. See http://askubuntu.com/a/268710/455619 Though [Googling for "linux/select.h" turns up basically nothing](https://encrypted.google.com/search?hl=en&q=%22linux%2Fselect.h%22) and it isn't in [the Ubuntu packages either](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=linux%2Fselect.h&mode=filename&suite=yakkety&arch=any).

Comment: I don't know what, specifically, you're trying to build, but Contiki is not Linux.  It is conceivable that some Contiki applications could be built on Linux, but there's no reason to suppose that must be true of any that rely on OS-specific features, as yours seems to do.  Your problem arises from a mismatch between the application's expectations of the build environment and the actual build environment; you've not presented anything useful for recommending a solution.

Comment: When you say you're trying to compile a Contiki OS example on Ubuntu... do you mean you just downloaded the source of some Contiki program and tried to compile it on Ubuntu? I don't think that's going to work. Or do you mean you're using a Contiki VM like [Instant Contiki](http://contiki-os.org/start.html)?

Comment: The header file is included from the platform-specific configuration file. But we can't help you as the `slwstk6201a` is not a public Contiki platform. Google search for this together with Contiki returns just one result - your question.

Comment: The fundamental misunderstanding you seem to have is that cross-compiling Contiki will use Linux system headers under `/usr/include`. It won't. It will use the headers in your cross-compiler's include directory. The question should at least name the cross-compiler this platform is using.

Comment: I'm using GCC. The platform I used is one I'm trying to port the OS to, so indeed, this can not be found on the internet. For this port I'm trying to compile the hello-world example. Therefore I have to compile the source code, driven by Makefiles, or am I completely wrong here?

Comment: using `gcc`, for linux, a `hello-world` example can be done with:  `gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=gnu11 -o hello-world hello-world.c`

Comment: *Which* gcc? Your MCU surely isn't x86.

Comment: I'm thinking that I do not have enough understanding of building an application for an MCU using Make. Can Someone point me in the right direction?